# spring cloud gateway - Create dynamic java routes

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

I created my bean like this:

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder, LoggingGatewayFilterFactory loggingFactory) {
    return builder.routes()
            .route("configuracionApp",
                    r -> r.path("/configuracion")
                    .and().readBody(String.class, requestBody -> true)
                    .filters(
                            f -> f
                            .filter(loggingFactory.apply(new Config("My Custom Message", true, true)))
                            .modifyResponseBody(String.class, String.class, bodyRewrite)
                            )
                    .uri("lb://msapp")
                    )
            .route("configuracionHorario",
                    r -> r.path("/configuracion/horario")
                    .filters(
                            f -> f
                            .filter(loggingFactory.apply(new Config("My Custom Message", true, true)))
                            .modifyResponseBody(String.class, String.class, bodyRewrite)
                            )
                    .uri("lb://msapp")
                    )
            .build();
}
```

Everything works perfect, my only doubt is if I can create those routes from a list, and have that list in a yml file for example,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I define a list of routes in : 
**application.yml**

```
application:
  routes:
    - 
      id: referential
      path: /referential/**
      uri: https://referential.p.rapidapi.com
    - 
      id: muslimsalat
      path: /muslimsalat/**
      uri: https://muslimsalat.p.rapidapi.com
```

I define a configuration properties class to map properties in 
**RouteConfigProperties.java**

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import lombok.Data;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application")
@Data
public class RouteConfigProperties 
{
    private List<CustomRoute> routes;

    @Data
    public static class CustomRoute 
    {
        private String id;
        private String path;
        private String uri;
    }

}
```

Finally i define my GatewayRouteConfig class in 
**RouteConfig.java**

```
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteLocator;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder.Builder;

@Configuration
public class RouteConfig {
            
    private final RouteConfigProperties routeConfigProperties;

    public RouteConfig(RouteConfigProperties routeConfigProperties) {
        this.routeConfigProperties = routeConfigProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    RouteLocator staticRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) 
    {       
        Builder build = builder.routes();
    
        routeConfigProperties.getRoutes().forEach(customRoute -> {
        
             build.route(
                  customRoute.getId(), 
                  route -> route.path(customRoute.getPath())
                  .filters(filter -> filter.addRequestHeader("x-rapidapi-host", String.format("%s.p.rapidapi.com", customRoute.getId()))
                                           .addRequestHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "2bb4b6cd95msh13bd91f0c332909p10dc79jsn9e98442d4457")
                                           .rewritePath(String.format("/%s/(?<segment>.*)", customRoute.getId()), "/${segment}"))
                  .uri(customRoute.getUri()));
        
        });
    
        return build.build();
    }

}
```

Don't forget to enabled configuration properties in : 
**GatewayServiceApplication.java**

```
import org.sid.gatewayservice.config.RouteConfigProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ RouteConfigProperties.class })
public class GatewayServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want routes in a file, why not use the Path Route predicate provided by spring cloud gateway - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#the-path-route-predicate-factory

There is are a ton of filters there too that can change requests and responses.

To change requests and responses of routes that are not provided the filters provided by spring, you can create your own custom filters - `GlobalFilter` or `GatewayFilters`. For reference on how to implement, you can see [their repo](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/tree/main/spring-cloud-gateway-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/filter) (for eg. how did they implement AddRequestHeader filter).

While global filters apply to all routes. GatewayFilters can be mapped to a specific one. For example, if you created a custom Filter called `MyCustomFilter` and you want it to be applied only in `/foo/*` requests, you can do somehting like:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: 
        uri: https://example.org # or lb://my-service
        predicates:
        - Path=/foo/**
        filters:
        - MyCustomFilter
```

To check which filters got applied to which routes you can see in the [actuator gateway routes](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#verbose-actuator-format).

Comment: I was trying to do that but I want to access to the body of the request and response, so I need to use the .readBody method to access the body and as the documentation mention it is the only way to access the cachedRequestBodyObject attribute

Comment: In that case, i would suggest you implement GatewayFilter or GlobalFilters. I have editted my answer to give some info

Comment: I already try those ones, but I can't found a way to get the request body and the response body, I want to save both in mongo, I know that exists ModifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory and  ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory but cannot found a way to save both in the same mongo document

Comment: Well, usually the filters are there to enrich requests and responses. Note that the spring-cloud-gateway is a reactive stack, so you would need reactive spring data and reactive mongo drivers. Also, the whole code should be non-blocking else you will face strange issues.

Comment: So there is no way to do what I want? sorry If I don't understand correctly

Comment: There is, I am just saying that you have to look into - Spring Data MongoDB Reactive first, like how to use it and write non-blocking code. Then jump into implementing in Spring cloud-gateway filters.